# How to insert a line break in the body of mailto on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, email

In order to take advantage of iOS 14 default Mail app, we now use `"mailto"`. How can we insert line breaks into the body of the email?

None of the following methods work:

```
\n
\r
%0D%0A
%0D
<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Forget about it. Apple changed the line feed for security reasons. %0D%0A at this moment does not work.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681023

Answer (score 1):

This is working again in iOS 15. You can use \n

Answer (score -3):

To insert line breaks in the `mailto` body parameter on iOS, use:

```
\r\n
```